# Updating collection view items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have inserted a `collectionView` inside my `tableViewCell`.  `Tableview` contains the list of categories and the `collectionView` contains all the product. How can I have a different number of items in the `collectionView` based off of which table view row was selected? I've tried storing the selected table view row and using that to define the number of items to be returned however it either crashes with no error code, tells me the value is `nil` or just does not display any clitems in the `collectionView`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Below is my code:

My Custom table view cell:

```
extension ExpandableCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let toReturn = categoryItems.count

        return counter
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        //What is this CustomCollectionCell? Create a CustomCell with SubClass of UICollectionViewCell
        //Load images w.r.t IndexPath
        print(self.selectedCategory.description)
        let newArray = starbucksMenu[selectedCategory]
        //cell.image.image = UIImage(named: (allItems[selectedCategory]?[indexPath.row])!)
        cell.label.text = categoryItems[indexPath.row]
        //cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1




        return cell
    }
```

My table view delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        word = indexPath.row
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandableCell
            else { return }

        switch cell.isExpanded
        {
        case true:
            self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)
            self.selectedCategory = ""
        case false:
            self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)

        }



        self.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
        print(self.selectedCategory)
        //self.array = starbucksMenu[starbucksMenuCategories[indexPath.row]]!
        //self.collectionView.reloadData()
        cell.menuItems = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        cell.categoryItems = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded
        self.itemsArray = allItems[selectedCategory]!
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()




        }
```

I've tried many things, I've tried adding the items in an array and returning the count (displays nothing). I have a dictionary with the necessary items so I've also tried returning allItems[selectedCategory]?.count and this always returns an error, I believe selectedCategory has no value once this is called.

Comment: Could you please show your code aswell?

Comment: @Victor I have added my code, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop of collection view item with appropriate operation Between beginUpdate() and endUpdate()